# how to expand the range of org-clock-display

Tags: org-mode, org-clock

Recently I upgraded my emacs from 24 to 25 and now when I do a org-clock-display command in one of my org files it only shows me the total for the current year, not previous years.

Is it possible to adjust the range in which org-clock-display will check?

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** I've now tried **org-mode 8.3.2**. There `org-mode-display`is rewritten. See the new documentation of `org-mode-display`. If you run `org-mode-display` with two prefix args then you can input the time range.

For the range you have the following choices (just try tab):
"today" "yesterday" "thisweek" "lastweek"
               "thismonth" "lastmonth" "thisyear" "lastyear"
               "interactive".

You can customize the default range with the option `org-clock-display-default-range`. The original value of this option is `thisyear` which explains your results.
If you set its value to `untilnow` you get the summation without lower bound.

---

**The following text regards org-mode 8.2.X only.**

Note at first that I have GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2015-11-10 with org-mode 8.2.10. There, I cannot reconstruct the effect that time is summed only over the current year.

---

Now, to your question:

> Is it possible to adjust the range in which org-clock-display will check?

I found that `(org-clock-sum)` is hard-wired in `(org-clock-display)` without the optional `tstart` and `tend` arguments of `org-clock-sum`.

So, some hack is required to accept clock intervals in `org-clock-display`.
The following **new** command `org-clock-interval-display` asks for a start and an end time for summing the time.

Note, the `total-only` option in `org-clock-display` is broken. So I did remove it in `org-clock-interval-display`. One can add it without problems via `current-prefix-arg` in the `interactive`-list in `org-clock-interval-display` if it is fixed in `org-clock-display`. But, before you do that you should rather issue a feature request for adding optional interactive `tstart` and `tstop` arguments to `org-clock-display`.

```lisp
(defmacro with-current-fset (backup symbol function &rest body)
  "Save SYMBOL's function definition in BACKUP,
set it temporarily to FUNCTION, and execute BODY.
After the execution of BODY the function definition of SYMBOL is restored."
  (declare (debug (sexp sexp function-form body)) (indent 3))
  `(let ((,backup (symbol-function ',symbol)))
     (unwind-protect
     (progn
       (fset ',symbol ,function)
       ,@body)
       (fset ',symbol ,backup))))

(defun org-clock-interval-display (tstart tend)
  "Like `org-clock-display' but considers tstart and tstop for `org-clock-sum'."
  (interactive (list (org-read-date t t nil "Start time:")
             (org-read-date t t nil "Stop time:")))
  (with-current-fset --org-clock-sum org-clock-sum (lambda () (funcall --org-clock-sum tstart tend))
    (org-clock-display)))
```